# NSTimer time format acting odd

Tags: macos, nstimer

I have and NSTimer and when trying to format it into MM:SS, the counter on counts to one second and then stops. This only happens ass soon as i divide seconds by 60. I can't seem to see why. Any suggestions?

```
- (void)showActivity{
    int currentTime = [time.text intValue];
    int newTime = currentTime + 1;
    int seconds = newTime % 60;
    //int minutes = newTime / 60;
    time.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", seconds];
}
- (void)delayedMethod {
    //Delay this action
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    timeTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(showActivity) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The %d format string is for decimal values, and you want to use integers. This often leads to weirdness. Try using:

```
time.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i", minutes, seconds];
```

Comment: tried replacing the division sign with the multiplication and it works, although as soon as i divide again, it doesn't work. Strange.

Comment: have you tried putting an NSLog statement in to see what the integer value you are getting actually is? You seem to be using time.text in two different ways. Initially you get an integer value from it, but then you reset it to a MM:SS representation of the time. It would help if you attach the code for how time.text is being generated.

Comment: See my code above, I edited it. The delayed method is called with an IBAction.